# S.O.A. with .NET for scalability

Tags: .net, performance, web-applications, scalability, soa

Anyone know where I can find useful resource for some information for this.
I reckon SOA is the way to go for scalabilty, but are there down sides such as performance and security I should look at.
Overall what architecture should be considered best for enterprise web applications

A good , complete, up to date book would be valuable, any suggestions?

Comment: Every project I've ever seen that was SOA-based was slow as hell :-)

Comment: That's my concern :), would the alternative be a web farm scenario with logical tiers, which is how I currently design web apps. I was trying to get a handle on the perceived wisdom on whether or not I should look at distributed systems. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article with some real performance data on systems where every class is a service

[WCF Service Performance](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/WCF-Service-Performance)

Comment: I want to follow you on twitter. Please tell me your twitter handle.
I am studying SOA.

Comment: http://hubpages.com/profile/MetalLemon is the best but you can follow metal_lemon on twitter

Answer (score 0):

I would say first take a look at [Microsoft's Patterns and Practices.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx)

Specifically I would say:

[Architecture Guide](http://services.social.microsoft.com/feeds/FeedItem?feedId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&itemId=e3956f93-222d-4280-ad35-b903c3e28d4f&title=Microsoft+Application+Architecture+Guide%3a+2nd+Edition+(October+2009)&uri=http%3a%2f%2fmsdn.microsoft.com%2fen-us%2flibrary%2fdd673617.aspx&k=%2bVxtXzpC7Q1vDtyeDpljjzFl%2fh2LNVdvHsfSZhZlqyE%3d)

[Web Client Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264518.aspx?rssCatalog&v2.0)

Here are also some good MSDN Articles:

[Understanding SOA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480021.aspx)